# Error on application ID of facebook app in Manifest

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

Here is a little detail about my app. I have a tab layout using `Fragments` and a `ViewPager`. On the third tab, I have a Google Map V2. Now, whenever the user of the app would be in a certain landmark, he can share the details about that landmark on facebook. I have successfully created the map, but the details about landmarks are yet to be done. Now about the "share" function of facebook, I have followed the steps on [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/). When I run the app, I get the error:

```
10-17 14:19:06.856: E/AndroidRuntime(2180): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
```

And after searching, I found out that I need to put the application ID on the `manifest.xml`.

**Here is my meta-data:**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="the key from google api console"

         />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="the key from fb devs"

        />
```

**However, I still get the error:**

```
10-17 14:44:03.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2240): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
```

The whole facebook share dialog is located in a `Fragment`.

Here it is:

**TabFour.java**

```
public class TabFour extends Fragment {
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_four, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("book", "https://example.com/book/Snow-Crash.html");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "books.reads", "book")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {


    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

}

**Here is my [logcat.](http://shrib.com/appID)**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You cannot put the appID directly into the manifest itself, you need to reference a string resource in the manifest. Something like:

In your AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

In your strings.xml

```
<resources>
  ...
  <string name="app_id">$app_id_here</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is important to bear in mind that you have to paste the meta-data element **WITHIN THE APPLICATION TAGS**.

This way:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
</application>
```

If you paste it somewhere else, you will keep getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that actually be:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:resource="@string/app_id"/>
```

Note the change from android:value to android:resource.

Comment: I would like to emphasize Steve's comment. You saved me a needle in a hay stack of a problem Steve. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Incase anyone is still having problems with this, here's the solution I found:

I was still getting a manifest merge error when I made these changes. 
I noticed that if I changed **android:value** to **android:resource**, I could fire off the app **but it would still crash** when I tried to launch facebook. I found the solution while in the "Merged Manifest" tab at the bottom of the screen when looking at the android Manifest.xml. Code as follows:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
   tools:replace="android:value"
   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Notice the `tools:replace="android:value"`  comes before `android:value` This is important for the flow and fixed my problem.

Hope this helps!