# Getting an Error on application ID of facebook app in Manifest

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing a weird behavior while generating signed apk. In my app I am integrating facebook integration and using facebook app id in string and giving reference from string resource file. Since my app is multi lingual it is giving me below error.

[image: This is the error]

as mentioned in below link I am giving app id in string file

[Error on application ID of facebook app in Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485492/error-on-application-id-of-facebook-app-in-manifest)

as I am developing multi lingual app and created 2 string files and created a string with name 'facebook_app_id' in both files. I don't know the reason while I am giving the same name in both files

Comment: Put fb in res->strings.xml and then try please.

Comment: could you please give further explanation of your point?

Comment: Currently your fb id is in res->values-sv/strings.xml. Please change to res->values->strings.xml

Comment: but string file is always found in res-> value folder. You mean I should create separate string file and in that I should create that string id?
Currently, i m having my fb id in 2 string files one for normal string file and second one for sweedish version as mentioned sv folder

Comment: Sorry i edited my comment. Please check now

Comment: i have my fb id in res-> values -> strings.xml and in res-> values-sv -> strings.xml as well in both folders I am keeping app id  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118416/discussion-between-jagjit-singh-and-abdul-waheed).

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem by just adding the below lines in meta tag line.

tools:ignore="ManifestResource"

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
    tools:ignore="ManifestResource" />
```

as mentioned here

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194705