# Android needs to initialise Facebook SDK, but is already initialized

Tags: android, android-facebook

I'm getting the error:

> A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set
>   by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.

My codes:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="1xxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
context = this;

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

fabFB = findViewById(R.id.fabFb);


fabFB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(context);
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentDescription("Description")
         .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://mywebsite.com")).build();
                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
        });
```

There is the right `AppId` in the `Manifest` file, and still I'm getting that error.

I don't want to use the facebook login, only to share pages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might be putting "AppID" directly in your Manifest files if I am not wrong. Try by adding through `strings.xml` file.

Comment: I get the same error @AndroidExpert

Comment: One more thing, put `<meta-data>` tag under <`application ...../>` tag

Comment: If you add it as answer, I going to mark it as the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can upvote here, same answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754657/1545584